# Steal private member from a Struct that is returned by a getter

Tags: rust

im in the following situation: I parse a bibtex file using nom_bibtex.
I want to do the following:

```rust
fn load_bibliography() -> DynResult<Vec<Bibliography>> {
    let bib_contents = fs::read_to_string("bibliography.bib")?;
    Ok(*Bibtex::parse(&bib_contents)?.bibliographies())
}
```

It does not work due to Rusts borrowing rules.

```
   Compiling bman v0.1.0 (/home/Uzaku/git/bman)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:35:8
   |
35 |     Ok(*Bibtex::parse(&bib_contents)?.bibliographies())
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::vec::Vec<nom_bibtex::model::Bibliography>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I also tried a `.to_vec()` call on the bibliography instead of dereferencing it, but that does not work as `Bibliography` does not implement `Clone`. Also it would have been an unnecessary copy, which I actually wouldn't want. The thing is, that I don't care about the other elements of the `Bibtex` struct, and don't want to drag them around. Also it obviously goes out of scope after this function anyway, so I'd assume "stealing" the bibliography from it would be fine. The problem is: I dont know how. I'd have tried `mem::take` or `mem::replace`, but I only have an immutable reference, as the actual `bibliographies` field is private.

Comment: You may consider opening a PR to the crate: (1) It's strange that `Bibliography` doesn't implement `Clone`, (2) It's unidiomatic to return `&Vec<T>`, the return type should really be `&[T]`, (3) an `into_bibliographies(self) -> Vec<Bibliography>` would clearly be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the issue of `Bibliography` not implementing `Clone` by using the constructor of the class `Bibliography::new` and iterating over your references.

```rust
if let Ok(bibtex) = Bibtex::parse(&bib_contents) {
    let bibs = bibtex
        .bibliographies()
        .iter()
        .map(|b| {
            Bibliography::new(
                b.entry_type().to_owned(),
                b.citation_key().to_owned(),
                b.tags().to_vec(),
            )
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    Ok(bibs)
}
else {
    panic!("Cannot parse bibtex contents.");
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But is there also a way that does not make a copy? Since The Bibtex object goes out of scope anyway it would feel better to reuse the existing vector instead of creating a new one. Although I have to admit that that's a pretty insignificant optimization.

Comment: @Uzaku You are only given an immutable reference access to the bibliographies field. The only way you can own the data is to copy these references. 
If you want to avoid copying them, then you should keep the whole `Bibtex` object.

Comment: @Uzaku alternatively, use `raw_parse` which will return a vector of events-ish, from which you can create the bibliographies without needing to copy them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like allocating a fresh vector, as done in @Sunreef's answer, you can return an iterator that captures the parsed bibliography and yields bibliographies one by one. Unfortunately you will still need to "clone" individual bibliographies, as Rust won't allow returning references into the inside of the iterator - but you will avoid creating the whole vector upfront:

```
fn load_bibliography() -> impl Iterator<Item = Bibliography> {
    let bib_contents = std::fs::read_to_string("bibliography.bib").unwrap();
    let bibtex = Bibtex::parse(&bib_contents).unwrap();
    let mut ind = 0;
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        if ind < bibtex.bibliographies().len() {
            let bib = &bibtex.bibliographies()[ind];
            ind += 1;
            Some(Bibliography::new(
                bib.entry_type().to_string(),
                bib.citation_key().to_string(),
                bib.tags().to_vec(),
            ))
        } else {
            None
        }
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef3d847b235b81b59f818ebb7aeb8370)